# Class instance type checking mypy python

Tags: python, typechecking, mypy

I have following two classes in two different python Modules

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,data:int)-> None: 
        if data is not None:
            self._index:int = data 



    def get_node_index(self)->int:
        if self._index is not None:
            return self._index
```

AND

```
from Graph import Node 

class NodeTest(object): 
    def func(self):
        n = Node(4) 
        print(n.get_node_index()) 
        data:bool = n.get_node_index() 
        print(type(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     a = A()
     a.func()
```

I get the following output when i run main in second class

```
4
<class 'int'>
```

I can't understand why mypy is not warning that type of data has to be **int** if i'm assigning it using `n.get_node_index()` which has a return type of **int**

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to pass [`--check-untyped-defs`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code) to `mypy`

for example, the following doesn't give any errors by default:

```
def foo():
  a = 5
  b: bool = a
```

but when run as `mypy --check-untyped-defs foo.py` I get:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "bool")

as @Michael0x2a pointed out you can also pass `--disallow-untyped-defs` to `mypy` which will cause it to complain that your `NodeTest.func` is untyped and hence it won't be checked.  You'd then want to annotate it to be:

```
    def func(self) -> None:
```

allowing it to be type-checked.

Comment: Or alternatively, the `--disallow-untyped-defs` flag, if you prefer fixing functions missing type hints immediately. Also, it's probably worth noting that the reason this function/the function in the question are considered untyped is because they're both completely missing in type hints -- you'd need to add in the missing return type hint of `-> None`. (Not sure if OP knew this, or just forgot.)

Comment: @Michael0x2a have expanded my answer...  just noticed that you've answered very similar questions quite a few times now!